# Как обойти блокировку инстаграм?

Tags: php, бот, instagram

У меня есть php скрипт для подписки на пользователей, после каждой подписки я отправляю скрипт в сон на 61 секунду, так как нашел, что запросы не должны идти чаще чем 1 в минуту. Но это мне не помогает и со временем инстаграм всё равно блокирует мои запросы. Как можно это обойти? Использую библиотеку  [mgp25/instagram](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)

Comment: Это тебе на zismo

Answer (score 0):

у инстаграмма есть алгоритм поиска "спамеров" и соответственно есть лимиты на различные действия. Система практически полностью автоматическая и точных правил и лимитов не знает никто кроме самой инсты. Так же со временем алгоритмы меняются и подстраиваются под новые реалии. Решением может быть мониторинг рекомендаций и новостей различных СММ сервисов (сммпланер, тулиграм и тд)

вот например свежая [статья](https://instaplus.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/6000056740-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B) с рекомендациями о лимитах инстаграмма

> ...Инстаграм ввёл новые лимиты на подписки, поэтому мы рекомендуем задавать не больше 300 подписок в сутки и 6000 подписок в месяц ...